# Are there different revisions of Arduino Uno SMD?

Tags: arduino-uno-smd, revisions

I know there are different revisions of the Arduino Uno itself, but are there any revisions of the SMD? If they are is SMD R2 identical to through-hole R2? I have a board marked R2 SMD and I am wondering if that is the only version that they produced in SMD format and just are signifying that it is compatible with the standard R2.

Comment: I have a R3 SMD uno, if that helps

Comment: @TheDoctor I don't think there is an R3 SMD. The R2, R3 are for the DIP boards. The only SMD board is the "Uno SMD"

Comment: @sachleen -  Yep i do - see my answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only difference with the SMD Uno is the fact you can't remove the chip. There are also 2 extra analog comparators not connected to anything.

The SMD boards are compatible with the thru-hole boards, but they have SMD components, which apparently make them easier to make and cheaper. As I said before, the two extra analog inputs (A7 and A6) are left unconnected on the official boards.

Here is my Uno R3:

[image]